# iOS Swift Parallax header using a basic UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, parallax

How can I achieve the parallax stretchy header effect using a basic UIView?.
I already searched for similar question, but all I found was achieving
this effect using TableView and not using regular UIView.

here's how it looks like.

[image: Screenshot from an app called fubiz]

I suppose this could be the hierarchy of the above app.

```
    ---SuperView---
      -ScrollView-
         -ImageView
         -UIView(text content)
```